# Inserir imagem alinhada com <h>

Tags: html

Com base no HTML abaixo, como faria pra inserir uma imagem alinhada antes do primeiro `<h>` de tal forma que a imagem fique posicionada a esquerda. Os `<h>` estão posicionados no centro.

```
<header>    
    <div id="wrapper">      
        <div id="header">
            <h>Fábrica:<%= request.getAttribute("display-fabrica") %></h>
            <h>|</h>
            <h>Doca:<%= request.getAttribute("display-doca") %></h>     
        </div>
    </div>          
</header>
```

Comment: O que seria `<h>`? Não conheço essa tag.

Comment: Meu cade o seu CSS?

Comment: Opa, segue: header {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 height:52px; 
}

header div h {
 color:#4163b1;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 44px;
}

Comment: A imagem tem que ficar antes de um H em específico ou tem que ficar antes de todos?

Comment: Antes de todos.

Comment: Vc quer que a imagem fique "colada" nos <h> ou colada à esquerda da janela?

Comment: A imagem colada na borda esquerda, os <h> centralizados. A imagem e os <h> alinhados horizontalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode posicionar a imagem de forma absoluta dentro do `header`. Basta colocar a imagem como filho direto do `header` e adicionar a propriedade `position: relative;` no `header` e `position: absolute` na imagem, com `left` e `top` com o valor `0`.

Como a imagem terá `position absolute`, não interferirá nos `<h>`. Note que a imagem terá que ter a mesma altura do `header`, ou seja, `52px`:

```css
header{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   height:52px;
   position: relative;
}

header div h { color:#4163b1; font-weight: bold; font-size: 44px; }

header > img{
   height: 52px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>    
    <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
    <div id="wrapper">      
        <div id="header">
            <h>Fábrica:foo</h>
            <h>|</h>
            <h>Doca:foo</h>     
        </div>
    </div>          
</header>
```

Comment: Sam, funcionou. Valeu!

Comment: Legal. Saiba como agradecer lendo o [tour] do site.